# Как правильно закрыть от индексации часть URL

Tags: robots.txt

Имеются URL `/shop/show-products/153/1/10/bowmaster/date_asc/`

Мне нужно, чтобы `/shop/show-products/=/=/=/=/`, где `=` - что угодно, было открыто, а по `/date_asc/` он не переходил. Вместо date_asc могут быть еще другие варианты.

т.е. боты должны видеть `/shop/show-products/153/1/10/bowmaster/` но не должны ходить по `/shop/show-products/153/1/10/bowmaster/date_asc/`

---

`/153/1/10/bowmaster/` вот эта часть может быть любой

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно прочитать у яндекса [как использовать robots.txt](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml#how-to-create)

Думаю после прочтения будет внесена ясность.

Так же рекомендую обратить внимание на инструменты вебмастера. Там есть анализатор robots.txt, он поможет найти ошибки.

Цитируя указанный ресурс, приведу пример:

```
Disallow: /cgi-bin/*.aspx # запрещает '/cgi-bin/example.aspx'
                          # и '/cgi-bin/private/test.aspx'
Disallow: /*private # запрещает не только '/private',
                    # но и '/cgi-bin/private'
```

Применимо к Вашим ссылкам:

```
Disallow: /shop/show-products/153/1/10/bowmaster/date_asc*
```